# Knockout: Combining 2 custom bindings for digits - Financial data

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

good Day

I found the following two fiddles that does exactly what I want:

The [first Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rRaHm/14/) gives me decimal notation.

The [second Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R6MPU/140/) gives me digital grouping of numbers.

**My Question:** How do I combine both of them into one such that I can just use it like this:

```
<b data-bind="commaDecimalFormatter: myNumber">This will output both demical notation and digital grouping</b>
```

====================================================================================================================================================================

Fiddle 1 code:

```
// Formatting Functions
function formatWithComma(x, precision, seperator) {
    var options = {
        precision: precision || 2,
        seperator: seperator || '.'
    }
    var formatted = parseFloat(x,10).toFixed( options.precision );
    var regex = new RegExp(
            '^(\\d+)[^\\d](\\d{' + options.precision + '})$');
    formatted = formatted.replace(
        regex, '$1' + options.seperator + '$2');
    return formatted;
}

function reverseFormat(x, precision, seperator) {
    var options = {
        precision: precision || 2,
        seperator: seperator || ','
    }
    var regex = new RegExp(
        '^(\\d+)[^\\d](\\d+)$');
    var formatted = x.replace(regex, '$1.$2');
    return parseFloat( formatted );
}
// END: Formatting Functions


// Custom Binding - place this in a seperate .js file and reference it in your html
ko.bindingHandlers.commaDecimalFormatter = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {

        var observable = valueAccessor();

        var interceptor = ko.computed({
            read: function() {
                return formatWithComma( observable() );
            },
            write: function(newValue) {
                observable( reverseFormat(newValue) );
            }
        });

        if( element.tagName == 'INPUT' )
            ko.applyBindingsToNode( element , {
                value: interceptor
            } );
        else
            ko.applyBindingsToNode( element , {
                text: interceptor
            } );
    }
}

// this is your viewmodel
var vm = {
    myNumber: ko.observable(100000)
}

// when the DOM is ready, call ko.applyBindings with your viewmodel
$(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```

FIDDLE 2 Code:

```
(function(){
    var format = function(value) {
        toks = value.toFixed(2).replace('-', '').split('.');
        var display = '$' + $.map(toks[0].split('').reverse(), function(elm, i) {
            return [(i % 3 === 0 && i > 0 ? ',' : ''), elm];
        }).reverse().join('') + '.' + toks[1];

        return value < 0 ? '-' + display : display;
    };

ko.subscribable.fn.money = function() {
    var target = this;

    var writeTarget = function(value) {
        var stripped=value
            .replace(/[^0-9.-]/g, '');

        target(parseFloat(stripped));
    };

    var result = ko.computed({
        read: function() {
            return target();
        },
        write: writeTarget
    });

    result.formatted = ko.computed({
        read: function() {
            return format(target());
        },
        write: writeTarget
    });

    result.isNegative = ko.computed(function(){
        return target()<0;
    });

    return result;
};
})();

//Wire it up
$(function() {
    var viewModel = {
        Cash: ko.observable(1000000).money(),
    };


    viewModel.Total = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.Cash();
    }, viewModel).money();
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot combine the two functions. Try the following, since it does what you want: Both Decimal notation and Digit grouping:

JS:

```
function formatPrice(price) {
        return price.reverse().replace(/((?:\d{2})\d)/g, '$1 ').reverse();
    }

    // Need to extend String prototype for convinience
    String.prototype.reverse = function() {
        return this.split('').reverse().join('');
    }

    $('.myNumber').each(function(){
        $(this).html(formatPrice($(this).html()));
    });
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rRaHm/16/)

NOTE: You need to refresh the browser everytime for the jquery to format the output value(Read Only) into digit grouping...That is of course when you enter a new value into the editor screen(first field) and you don't see the digit grouping updated

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to provide an alternative solution.  You could also create a custom binding handler that does what you want (which would use the syntax you originally proposed).

```
ko.bindingHandlers. commaDecimalFormatter = {
  update: function(element, valueAccessor, allValuesAccessor) {

    // This gets the current value of the observable from your model
    var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

    // Manipulate `value` as desired using the bodies of the functions you mentioned
    // Note: You don't want to use a global function, so actually take the bodies 
    // and put it here. Plain old JS :)
    ...

   // Set the value on the element
   jQuery(element).text(value);
  }
};
```